# aliases do not work in bash - login shell

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I have an alias defined in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` as:

```
alias e='echo'
```

When I run the command as:

```
bash -c 'e hello'
```

It shows error as:

```
bash: e: command not found
```

But from an interactive bash shell, when I run the command `e hello`, it prints `hello`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you invoke `bash` only by:

```
bash -c 'cmd'
```

Then `bash` will be a non-interactive, non-login shell, therefore it will not source any rc scripts.

If you want `~/.bashrc` to be sourced, call `bash` by:

```
bash -ic 'e hello'
```

With the `-i` flag `bash` is called as interactive non-login shell. Then `bash` sources the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Be careful with such constructs: Compatible shells like the Bourne Shell, ksh88 or ksh93 will print a prompt before executing a command if the shell is interactive.

Answer (score -1):

add to .profile or similar ~/.bash_profile

```
e(){
ECHO_COMMAND=`which echo`
$ECHO_COMMAND "$@"
}
```

Relogin or run

```
test@term{~}:source .profile
```

Test it:

```
test@term{~}:e hello
hello
```